# How does resolver verify DNS response?

Tags: dns

When a client issues a DNS query, it goes to the DNS server and we get a response. I understand DNSSEC can be enabled on DNS server, and that does signature validation on queries.

Is it possible to do DNS validation by client, apart from validation by upstream DNS server? What is the overhead cost of enabling DNSSEC?

Comment: How to enable dnssec validation on the client

Answer (score 0):

Yes, anyone who feels like it can validate DNSSEC. While it is common to let a recursing resolver do it for you, strictly speaking it's more correct security-wise to do it locally on your own machine.

*How* you do it on your own machine is another question entirely, and depends on too many things to even start to answer here.

The overhead of using DNSSEC is more bytes transferred over the network (signatures, keys and such need to be included), more RAM to store a zone in memory (again, signature and keys take up space) and more CPU used (for cryptographic calculations). The overhead is only noticeable if you're in a constrained environment (embedded system, very little bandwidth, something like that) or if you processes hundreds of DNS packets per second.